# Установить thumb по центру в динамическом seekbar

Tags: java, android, view

День добрый.
Проблема заключается в том, что у меня seekbar может в процессе работы приложения изменять свои параметры высоты и ширины, при изменении thumb не хочет становиться по центру слайдера и всегда остается на одном месте (по вертикали).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Находил ответы о одинаковых minHeight и maxHeight, для меня не подходит т.к. динамический.
Еще писали о maxHeight>1000dip, тоже не работает.